# Too small learning rate for multiple linear regression

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, learning-rate

I'm trying to build a multiple linear regression model for `boston` dataset in scikit-learn.

I use Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) to optimize the model. And it seems like I have to use very small learning rate(0.000000001) to make model learn. If I use bigger learning rate, the model fails to learn and diverges to NaN or inf.

So, here's my questions:

1. Is it okay to use such small learning rate? Or is there any problem in my code below?
2. It seems like the loss of validation dataset decreases, increases a while, and then decreases again. Is this the case that my model fall into overfitting problem, but luckily escaped due to the power of SGD's instability compare to Batch Gradient Descent method?

Here's my code:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loss(x, y, w):
    predict_y = x @ w
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((y - predict_y))))

def status(w):
    w_ = np.squeeze(w)
    print("w = [", end="")
    for i in range(14):
        if(i == 13):
            print(w_[i], end="]")
        else:
            print(w_[i], end=", ") 
    print()

    training_loss = loss(training_x, training_y, w)
    validation_loss = loss(validation_x, validation_y, w)
    print("Training Loss = " + str(training_loss))
    print("Validation Loss = " + str(validation_loss))

    training_predict_y = training_x @ w
    validation_predict_y = validation_x @ w

    print("{:^40s}|{:^40s}".format("training", "validation"))
    print("{:^20s}{:^20s}|{:^20s}{:^20s}".format("predict_y", "true_y", "predict_y", "true_y"))
    for i in range(10):
        print("{:^20f}{:^20f}|{:^20f}{:^20f}".format(float(training_predict_y[i]), float(training_y[i]), float(validation_predict_y[i]), float(validation_y[i])))
    print()

def plot(title, data):
    plt.title(title)
    plt.plot(range(len(data)), data)
    plt.savefig(title + ".png", dpi = 300)
    plt.show()

np.random.seed(2020) # for consistency

# data
dataset = datasets.load_boston()
x = dataset.data
y = dataset.target

# reformat the data
x_ = np.concatenate((np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)), x), axis=1) # x0 = 1인 열 추가
y_ = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)

# divide data into training set and validation set
training_x = x_[ 0:406, : ]
training_y = y_[ 0:406, : ]

validation_x = x_[ 406:506, : ]
validation_y = y_[ 406:506, : ]

# initialize w
w = np.random.rand(x_.shape[1], 1)
print("Before Training...")
status(w)

# hyperparameter
epochs = 100000
lr = 0.000000001

training_losses = []
validation_losses = []
data_num = training_x.shape[0]
for epoch in range(epochs):    
    for i in range(data_num):
        sample = training_x[ i:i + 1, : ]
        true_y = training_y[ i:i + 1, : ]

        predict_y = sample @ w

        # calculate gradient
        gradient = -(2 / sample.shape[0]) * sample.T @ (true_y - predict_y)

        # update w
        w = w - lr * gradient

    training_loss = loss(training_x, training_y, w)
    validation_loss = loss(validation_x, validation_y, w)
    training_losses.append(training_loss)
    validation_losses.append(validation_loss)

print("After Training...")
status(w)

plot("Training Loss - SGD", training_losses)
plot("Validation Loss - SGD", validation_losses)
```

Here's the loss curve of the validation dataset.
[image: Validation Loss - SGD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that mysterious small learning rate is because I did not normalize the input data. Data must be normalized if the scale of features varies. I normalized the data, and I could make the model learned with reasonable learning rate(0.001).